# Oracle order. First letters and after numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a Spring Boot appl. that uses JdbcTemplate to access an Oracle DB
I am working on a `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

I am working in a query that have severals joins to return some values ordered by a field that is `VARCHAR2(50)` type. I would like to order with this criteria: first the letters and last all the numbers

```
  select vo_group.company_nr, vo_group.name name, count_vehicle, count_person, count_key_code 
         from vo_group 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (select vo_group.vo_group_id, count(*) count_vehicle 
            from vo_group, vo_group_vehicle, vehicle  
            where vo_group.vo_group_id=vo_group_vehicle.vo_group_id 
        and vo_group_vehicle.vehicle_id=vehicle.vehicle_id 
            and vehicle.vo_vehicle_category_id=1202270 
            and parent_vo_group_id=20009 
            group by vo_group.vo_group_id 
        ) g_veh ON vo_group.vo_group_id=g_veh.vo_group_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (select vo_group.vo_group_id, count(*) count_person 
            from vo_group, vo_group_person, person 
            where vo_group.vo_group_id=vo_group_person.vo_group_id 
            and vo_group_person.person_id=person.person_id 
            and person.vo_person_category_id=1006590 
            and parent_vo_group_id=20900 
            group by vo_group.vo_group_id 
        ) g_pers ON vo_group.vo_group_id=g_pers.vo_group_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (select vo_group.vo_group_id, count(*) count_key_code 
            from vo_group, vo_group_person, key_code 
            where vo_group.vo_group_id=vo_group_person.vo_group_id  
            and parent_vo_group_id=20090 
            and vo_group_person.person_id = key_code.person_id 
            group by vo_group.vo_group_id 
            ) g_key ON vo_group.vo_group_id=g_key.vo_group_id 
        where parent_vo_group_id=20900 
        order by name
```

That gives me this result:

```
01411 Distribution Iberia Telecom
101412 Distribution Iberia Power
101440
101545 TDK - Airport Systems
101563 TDK - Waterways North
101564 TDK - Waterways Technics North
101565 TDK - Marine Technics
101590
101593 TDK - Security Aartselaar
101594 TDK - Security Braine
101595 TDK - Security Zaragoza
101842
102441
102470
102610 TDK Panels
103330
202410
202412
202423
202431
202432
202442
202443
202480
222631 TDK Frame agreements
222632 TDK Engineering Revisions
222633 TDK Machining on site
222673
80E510
ATV Technica
BUILDINGS
Buildings - Airdselaar
Buildings - Brainesa
```

Is there a way return first letters and then numbers? like

```
ATV Technica
BUILDINGS
Buildings - Airdselaar
Buildings - Brainesa
101411 Distribution Iberia Telecom
101412 Distribution Iberia Power
101440
101545 TDK - Airport Systems
101563 TDK - Waterways North
101564 TDK - Waterways Technics North
101565 TDK - Marine Technics
101590
101593 TDK - Security Aartselaar
101594 TDK - Security Braine
101595 TDK - Security Zaragoza
101842
102441
102470
102610 TDK Panels
103330
202410
202412
202423
202431
202432
202442
202443
202480
222631 TDK Frame agreements
222632 TDK Engineering Revisions
222633 TDK Machining on site
222673
80E510
```

Comment: is the string format consistent when you have numbers? i.e. number followed by a space followed by alphabets (if any).

Comment: yes, indeed. This is always the pattern

Comment: Do you need the "unusual" ordering only for the BEGINNING of the string, or for EVERYTHING within the strings, anywhere? So, for example, you want `'aa bb'` to come before `'22 bb'`. Do you ALSO want `'aa bb'` to come before `'aa 22'`? Or is it just that strings that BEGIN with a substring of digits and a space must be at the end, but otherwise still use "normal" ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with tab as(
select '11' as name from dual union all
select '11 a' from dual union all
select '11 b' from dual union all
select 'aa 11' from dual union all
select 'aa' from dual union all
select 'aaaa t' from dual union all
select 'bbbb 23' from dual union all
select '32' from dual
)

select col, regexp_substr(name, '[^[:digit:]]*')
from tab
order by regexp_substr(name, '[^[:digit:]]*'), 
         name;
```

The regexp_substr <strike>trims the leading digits</strike> gets all the nondigits charachters from the begining of the column. 
See the result, I've let the column there to see the values of regexp expression:

```
name       REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,'[^[:DIGIT:]]*')
aa         aa
aa 11      aa 
aaaa t     aaaa t
bbbb 23    bbbb 
11         null
11 a       null
11 b       null
32         null
```

Comment: the problem with this is the numbers would get ordered as strings..not actual numbers.

Comment: No - the result does not trim the leading digits. Just look at your inputs `11 a` and `11 b` - the REGEXP trimmed EVERYTHING (look at the resulting column). An empty match is valid when using the * operator, and that is found BEFORE the first digit, if the string begins with a digit.

Comment: Which means all the inputs that begin with a digit are output in arbitrary order with this solution.

Comment: @mathguy your first comment is correct. The second is not. I've ordered also by `name`.

Comment: @mathguy now corrected the explanation of regexp :)

Comment: You are right - second order criterion does the job.